# How to generating a unique long from a unique string?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bytebuffer

I have a situation where each object in a JSON has a unique string associated with it. I need to turn this into a unique long. Here is the code I am currently using but I have no idea if it works or if I am using these classes correctly.

```
public long getUniqueId() {
  final byte[] vinStrBytes = vin.getBytes();
  final ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(vinStrBytes);
  return byteBuffer.getLong();
}
```

To specify, my concern is that the `long` is also unique, and can be used to identify the object.

The strings are Vehicle Identification Numbers such as `"WME4513341K416232"`.

In Android the list's [**`Adapter`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId(int)) requires a `long` for a unique identifier.

Comment: are you changing the data inside the JSON object or using the unique long outside of the JSON for some container?

Comment: Could you give an example for one of your Strings? If it wasn't long, you could use `hashCode()` (but this an `int` type)

Comment: the latter, the long is being used outside the JSON

Comment: the strings are Vehicle Identification Numbers such as "WME4513341K416232"

Comment: hashCode is not unique! never use it. BTW usage of long as unique identifier is not a good idea at all. Why do you need it if you already have globally unique identifier?

Comment: I am using it because in Android the list adapter requires a long for a unique identifier.

Comment: You will not be able to guarantee unique long values, sorry. There are more possible `String` values than long values. I suggest getting to know the possible vehicle registration numbers and inventing a mapping specifically for them.

Comment: @Ole V.V. - Agreed. Also, if that value needs only in currently running Application context it can be just a sequence of long values.

Comment: @Moses, use the [**`edit`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41727634/edit) button (small options text under Question) to add any new info or fix anything that is not correct.